# How to import file from lib into file outside of lib in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have customised a Flutter package and therefore it's outside of my lib folder.

Structure:

- project_name

  - lib

    - file.dart
  - package

    - package_file.dart

I want to import file.dart into package_file.dart. How can I achieve this?
Tried import 'package:project_name/lib/file.dart' but it says URI not exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Import dart file outside lib directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54197007/import-dart-file-outside-lib-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have pubspec.yaml in your package module and declare your project root file packages yaml's dependencies like this :

```
dependencies:

  ROOT_PROJECT_NAME:
    path: ../../ROOT_PROJECT_NAME
```

Comment: Man I have something similar. I am working with aws amplify and it generates the models folder automatically in the lib folder. In my case, the package is imported in the lib as a dependency. If I now import the root project into the package I will create a dependency cycle. Would you still recommend your proposal for this?