# How to include a source-file in flutter which is not inside my app-folder?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

So, I started to do some first steps writing Flutter in Visual Studio Code on Windows.

I have written a small example. To get a better overview, I outsourced some of my widget-classes to another sub-folder, like:

```
/my-app/
/my-app/lib/main.dart
/my-app/lib/classes/class1.dart
/my-app/lib/classes/class2.dart
/my-app/lib/classes/class3.dart
```

Inside my main.dart, I'm doing:

```
import '/classes/class1.dart';
```

which works fine. I'm using "import" in the same way a "include" would be done in C++-source-code.

So, now I have ANOTHER app in which I want to use some of the classes. Of course (to keep maintaining simple) it would be great to share these classes between the apps. So the idea is to use a dir-structure like:

```
/my-app/
/my-app/lib/main.dart

/my-new-app/
/my-new-app/lib/main.dart

/shared-classes/class1.dart
/shared-classes/class2.dart
/shared-classes/class3.dart
```

But I fail to include /shared-classes/class1.dart into any main.dart. Something like:

```
import '../../shared-classes/class1.dart';
```

or

```
part '../../shared-classes/class1.dart';
```

or even

```
import '[full-path]/shared-classes/class1.dart';
```

doesn't work (Error "Target of URI doesn't exist").

I now I could create an package out of it, but this seems a bit exaggerated in this case.

Comment: Have you checked this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54197084/9455325

Comment: So I see there is no other way then to create a package - will try it. Thanks for putting me into the right direction.